# How to check number of bytes read from disk by mmap

Tags: c, mmap

I was wondering how I can check the number of bytes that is read from disk by mmap(). Is total_pgmajfault * the page size a correct measure?

Comment: I think you have to call `stat` on the file, and check `st_size`.  Note that `mmap` doesn't really "read" the file.  It sets up a mapping between virtual memory and the file.  The actual bytes probably won't get read from the actual file until you try to access the bytes in memory.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yeah I'm just trying to figure out how much data is read by this mmap process, but not the actual file size. Then in this way shall I just use the major page faults * the page size?